# Erro Eclipse não econtra JVM

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

Olá, utilizo Linux Mint 16 e instalei o eclipse e rodei tranquilamente, só que após a instalação do eclipse eu desinstalei o OpenJDK 1.7 e instalei o JavaJDK 1.8. editei o arquivo /etc/profile acrescentando estas linhas:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk8u1
PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH export PATH JAVA_HOME
CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar
CLASSPATH=.:$CLASSPATH
export PATH JAVA_HOME CLASSPATH
```

Ao executar os comandos java -version e javac -version os resultados estão corretos mostrando que o java foi instalado com êxito. Abri o eclipse novamente e este é erro que está aparecendo:

```
Version 1.5.0 of the JVM is not suitable for this product. Version: 1.6 or greater is required.
```

É como se o eclipse estivesse visualizando somente a versão java que fica após desinstalar o OpenJDK.

Alguém pode me ajudar??

Comment: Assim que abre o eclipse já dá esse erro ou você tenta rodar algum projeto? É possível você colocar alguma imagem do erro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas versões do Eclipse no Linux:

- A versão do [site oficial do Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) é o que conversa com o JavaJDK (oficial da Oracle).
- A versão baixada via repositórios como o `apt-get` é a que conversa com o OpenJDK.

Tente baixar a versão do site oficial para ver se funciona.